# Long Ubuntu 12.04 booting time

Tags: 12.04, boot

Can someone help me with the delays in booting:

> [    6.034566] tg3 0000:01:00.0: eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
>   [   10.158037] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>   [   43.640175] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
>
> [   47.632127] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (2528) terminated with status 1
>   [   47.843599] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
>   [   58.376473] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
>   [   67.530222] cfg80211: Found new beacon on frequency: 2472 MHz (Ch 13) on phy0

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! You may want to add additional information about your system such as hardware information so that people have a better idea of what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something related with your video driver, because of plymouth crash.

Try updating your video driver to a recent version.

Comment: Plymouth crash? Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is hard with little info.